# Удалить из строки слова который начинаются с символа @

Tags: php

Необходимо удалить из строки все слова которые начинаются с символа **@**

То есть удалять от символа **@** (включительно) и до первого пробела или конца строки.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: сами то пытались решить?

Comment: может таки удалять надо первого разделителя, будь то пробел, запятая, двоеточие или еще чего нить?

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее всего не полностью решит твою изначальную проблему, так как скорее всего есть еще какие-то НО по типу тех, что назвал teran, а именно непонятно что делать с разделителями, оставшимися проблемами, но это в любом случае решает описанную сейчас тобой проблему и ты сможешь дописать этот код под себя либо попросить сделать это меня, если дашь больше вводных и тестовых данных, а также желаемый результат на конкретном примере.

```
<?php //php 7.2.24

    $text = 'word1 @word2 @word3 word4 @word5';
    $text = mb_ereg_replace('(@\S+)\s|(\s@\S+)$', '', $text);
    var_dump($text);

?>

>> string(11) "word1 word4"
```

Comment: `@(.*?)(\s|$)` нежадный поиск до пробела или конца строки